# auto generate OpenAPI json file in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-functions, swagger-2.0, azure-functions-runtime

I am developing Azure Functions in VS2017 5.13 (Preview) and I would like to generate project documentation from the OpenAPI (aka swagger) which i generated from azure portal.  The visual studio doesn’t generate the file, so I got the initial file from azure portal, but I want to keep this updated from the code automatically.

Is there official walkthrough on how to integrate swagger json file to generate documentations from code in VS 2017?

Comment: It seems that you have made a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/394), please wait for Azure Functions team member's response. Besides, you can also give a feedback on [Azure UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions).

Answer (score 3):

Right now your best bet is to use CI/CD to deploy your function. Then you can update the OpenAPI definition directly in  `\site\wwwroot\.azurefunctions\swagger\swagger.json`

The generator is portal only at the moment.